# Using TestNG, Two URL's are open instead of one

Tags: testng

Using TestNG, two methods are there, the first case having invalid credentials but in 2nd it's valid. The concern is First URL opened and added invalid credentials and then again URL opened and added valid details. Why URL opens twice.

```java
@Test(priority = 0)
public void one() {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='user_login']")).sendKeys("In Valid email");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='user_login_password']")).sendKeys("InValid password");
}

@Test(priority = 1)
public void two() {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='user_login']")).sendKeys("Valid");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='user_login_password']")).sendKeys("Valid");
}

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod() {
    // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    //Put a Implicit wait, this means that any search for elements on the page could take the time the implicit wait is set for before throwing exception
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //Launch the Online Store Website
    driver.get("URL");
}

@AfterMethod
public void afterMethod() {
    // Close the driver
    driver.quit();
}
```

Comment: It opens twice because you're initializing your webdriver object before each method, and not before test class. Makes sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

@BeforeMethod Will call before Every @Test Method which is defined in the class, So as you can see in your code there are 2 @Test annotation with the name 'void one()' and 'void two()' So your URL will open and pass keys for void one() method and browser will close as according to @AfterMethod annotation.

***As @BeforeMethod call before each @Test execution, Similarly @AfterMethod will call after each @Test execution.***

In order to execute it single time, you have to use **@BeforeClass** annotation so it will call single time and you will have your desired Result. Similarly to close browser after End of execution you can define it with **@AfterClass** annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Your running 2 methods but both are initializing the the @BeforeMethod. This will open the URl twice. Run a @Before test method instead